# Swift .xib File Table cell

Tags: ios, swift

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTvPu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qajes.png)

SO My label doesn't show up when run the program. I tried doing it through coding and also using writing hello and see if it shows up but it doesnt show up

EDIT :: [image]

Comment: what constraints you added on label ?

Comment: @Dhruv Patel You really need to provide a few more information. What kind of constraints did you use?

Comment: @christophriepe please check out the picture that i just procied it has all the constraints i have used

Comment: I think your label don't have any constraint right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing the image you just postet, I would say that you missed some constraints for the UILabel inside the bottom UIView.

> Your **UIView** has no constraints so far and you **UILabel** has no neither

The probably best solution would be to simply add `top, bottom, leading and trailing constraint` between your **UILabel** and your **UIView**. Maybe 20 or so.

That should solve your issue, since the UIView is collapsing the 0 height on runtime without any constraints.